# JMeter: doesn't increment counter value

Tags: jmeter

I'm working on a load test for Eclipse RAP-based application in JMeter. I need to replace requestCounter in each http request with variable. Variable should be incremented by 1 in next requests.

Tried to use JMeter's *__counter* function *${__counter(FALSE)}* for my *${COUNTER}* variable:

1) in User Defined Variables (didn't increment counter http://screencast.com/t/5MP1ovdHJN5p),

2) in CSV Data Set (function body was inserted instead of number http://screencast.com/t/mUIaYF3Oc).
Replaced *${__counter(FALSE)}* with *${__javaScript(${__counter(FALSE)})}* - still no success.

3) Counter config element brings the same result as User Defined Variable - not incrementing value for next request.

Plan:

+Thread_group

+Counter config element/User Defined Variables/CSV Data Set

+Request group

++ HTTP request1: {"head":{"requestCounter":${COUNTER}} #should be 1

++ HTTP request2: {"head":{"requestCounter":${COUNTER}} #should be 2

++ HTTP request2: {"head":{"requestCounter":${COUNTER}} #should be 3
...

Any suggestions?﻿

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to update the request counter manually. For RAP 2.1+ we updated the Wiki with the current info about load testing:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/LoadTesting